# How to set a variable as Date type in ejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date, datetime, ejs

I'm using express.js, mongoose and ejs, I have a Model like

```
var t_schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  startFrom: Date,
  ...
})

router.get('/', function(req,res) {
 t_model.findOne({name: req.body.name}, function(result) {res.render('t', result)})
})
```

So result contains a Date type startFrom

And in my ejs :

```
$('#startDate').datepicker.set(<%= result.startDate %>)
```

which is a String instead of Date, while datepicker.set needs Date.

How can I make result.startDate as a Date?

`$('#startDate').datepicker.set(new Date('<%= result.startDate %>'))`

seems work, but the timezone is incorrect.

And 2.)

What is the best practice to manipulate Date in Nodejs/mongodb?
My users will come from different timezone, so I would like to show datetime in their timezone in Browser, I think maybe its better to store date as UTC in Mongodb?

Comment: This would probably be more appropriate as two different questions.

Comment: what do you mean, 'timezone is incorrect'?

Comment: maybe the server's timezone and the browser's timezone is different?

Comment: As you said, users come from different timezones. You should assume browser and server have different timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer question 2 first, yes, it would be better to store date as UTC in mongo, then when displayed to the individual user, convert to localtime based on user browser timezone. Or not do any conversions and just say that the time is in UTC.

To answer the first question, your jquery datepicker can be set with:

```
Date date = new Date('<%= result.startDate %>'); 
$('#startDate').datepicker('setDate', date.toUTCString());
```

Comment: should I convert date to UTC in browser? different user's browser's timezone is different, and the server's timezone is different, either

Comment: I would have the data be stored in mongo as UTC. Its a design decision whether or not to display the time in local time, but I would have that be something handled with the browser, not on the server.